# Caching in Tomcat and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, caching

I have a web application that gets deployed as war file into a Tomcat container. The application itself has two main aspects:

1. It uses Spring MVC to provide REST endpoints
2. It ships an AngularJS based single page application as static content. Technically there is an `index.html` in the root webapp folder that uses an html `http-equiv="refresh"` redirect to redirect to the actual index.html in a subfolder.

When I update the application I frequently notice that the browser does not load the latest version from the server and just shows some older cached version. For example the website shows the current version number on the login page, so if I update it from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6, I often find that the browser still shows 1.0.5 even if I reload the page. Pressing `CTRL+F5` to ignore the cache usually solves this temporarily.

I am not very familiar with the whole caching topic, so I am looking for resources to get started.

*Questions:*

- Is the caching problem something that I must configure in Spring?
- Is it rather something that must be configured in Tomcat when I deploy the war file?
- Is it possible that the problem is caused by the html redirect mentioned above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "some old content" ? what old content , jsps, js files, images, properties files, java codes? what you exactly update? I guess, your application is not getting updated if you update app contents while tomcat server is running or do you see old content if you update app while tomcat being down too?

Comment: I have made some updates to the question, if I knew better what is causing this behavior I might be able to give more precise information.

Answer (score 1):

> Pressing CTRL+F5 to ignore the cache usually solves this temporarily.

I believe this means that the whole thing is in [browser caching/HTTP caching](http://www.pctools.com/security-news/what-is-a-browser-cache/).

#### Solution 1.

[Disable cache in Google Chrome](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache) via settings (or find a similar article for your browser).

#### Solution 2.

Browser caching is actually controlled by the [`Cache-Control`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header.

You can avoid this condition if you tell your browser not to cache the dynamic content. To do this, you'd have to write some cache-control header.

Well, in the Java Spring Framework, there is a very easy way to stop dynamic content caching. In your servlet context, just declare a bean `WebContentInterceptor` and define its properties.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Solution 1 is not applicable because that would only solve it for me but not for other less technical users. I will give solution 2 a try. Does Tomcat have any impact on caching?

Comment: Another question, will the interceptor only apply to the rest endpoints or also to the statically served content?

Comment: @lanoxx Tomcat server has its own cache. You can clear and [disable it](http://serverfault.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-disable-tomcat-caching-im-having-weird-static-file-problems). IDK if the interceptor applies to the statically served content. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

These tags should help to prevent reading from cache

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
```

The Cache-Control header was added in HTTP 1.1, while the other two were also present in HTTP 1.0.